# ¿Si mi ESP32 al conectarla enciende el LED de prueba parpadea como 2 veces y luego se mantiene apagado es normal?

Tags: puertos, esp32

Es la primera vez que la uso soy nuevo y compré una ESP32, no se que versión de modelo es, pero ya intente configurarlo en el Arduino IDE y por más que instale los drivers para el CP2102, no me reconoce ningún puerto nuevo en el administrador de dispositivos, por eso quiero saber si mi placa si funciona o quizá está dañada. Gracias :)

Actualización: Si pude el error si era el cable USB a microUSB, los baratos no funcionan :)

Comment: Hola Gaspar, bienvenido, la idea detrás del funcionamiento de este sitio, es ayudar a los programadores a resolver los problemas que se encuentran durante la creación de aplicaciones, por lo que probablemente, tu pregunta sea cerrada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

NO se si sera el caso a mi me paso lo mismo pero se resolvio buscando los drivers del puerto com y cargando la placa en la IDE ESP32 WROOM DEV Kit
Espero te sea da ayuda.-